# How do I import photos from my iPhone into a directory?

Tags: photos, import

I have a new MBP running Yosemite. I like to keep my pictures and videos on an external hard drive in a file system so I can navigate to them (e.g. using Finder, Terminal, or a Linux VM). Photos only imports into a photo library which is an opaque object storing your photos. How do I import my photos from my iPhone into a specified directory?
Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Image Capture application allows you to import photos and videos from connected devices into any folder you specify. (see: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH17894)

For organization, I use Adobe Lightroom, which also has the ability to import directly from iPhone.

Either way would be better than using Photos.